# Is there a possibility to reverse engineer the Masm and Nasm like assembler

Tags: disassembly

Hi i want to reverse engineer assembler itself. How the assembler like MASM AND NASM assemblers maintains the opcode, symbol table, relocation bits allocation linking loading  and how it takes input source code and converts to object file. How to reverse engineer the assembler using disassembler tool.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to reverse engineer NASM, it's [open-source](http://repo.or.cz/w/nasm.git). Other open-source assemblers:

- FASM: http://flatassembler.net/download.php
- YASM: http://yasm.tortall.net/Download.html
- JWASM (MASM clone): https://github.com/JWasm/JWasm
- GAS (GNU Asssembler): https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/